# Definition of positive definiteness with respect to inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, positive-definite

Why the condition of positive definiteness only depend on one single vector in the inner product?

> Positive Definite Matrices
>
> $$K\mapsto(\vec v,\vec w)=\vec v^Tk\vec w\\
> \text{Pos.Def.}:(\vec v,\vec v)=\vec v^Tk\vec v=||\vec v||^2$$

Only depends on $v$ here not $w$.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UIHcHdgulk&t=1455s

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, definiteness is a property we attribute to bilinear forms, but rather to *quadratic forms*. As it turns out, a quadratic form $Q(v)$ is derived from a symmetric bilinear form $B(v,w)$ where both arguments are the same vector.

Comment: Why do we attribute it to quadratic forms is my question?